# Attempting to copy a file from one directory to another in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am attempting to do some theme structure in my CMS, where you can select a theme for the front end website. This below is part of my code that happens as a certain theme is activated the idea is that it's meant to copy a file from the themes directory (in some form of upload directory) into the views folder in the application folder > views in codeigniter. This isn't really codeigniter specific but i'm still looking to copy my files and replace the existing theme files AND put the file there even if it doesn't exist.

```
 $this->data['main_url'] = FCPATH . 'assets/themes' . $name;
            foreach(glob($this->data['main_url'] . '/*.php') as $file) {
                if (file_exists($file)) {
                    if (basename($file) == '_main_layout.php' || basename($file) == '_login_layout.php' || basename($file) == '_register_layout.php') {
                        copy($file, APPPATH . 'views/' . basename($file));
                    } else {
                        $this->data['errors'][] = 'Please note you have included an invalid file. Valid files in the MAIN directory are: _main_layout.php, _login_layout.php and _register_layout.php. Please see the documentation for more information.';
                    }
                }
            }
```

Does anybody know what i am doing wrong here? Thank you.

EDIT: I'm getting no errors and the files aren't copying over the existing files nor copying and adding the new files

Comment: Which part is failing?

Comment: Well, I'm getting no errors and the files aren't copying over the existing files nor copying and adding the new files :/

Comment: may its directory permission issue. what is your views directory views permission? can you try again after set 777 permission to views directory?

Comment: Working locally and yes i do a check that the chmod is set to 777 before it can copy and if that fails there would be an error.

Comment: what is value of variable $name?

Comment: $name is simply the name of the theme in this case it would be theme101, simply what i named the theme.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51145/discussion-between-samiul-amin-shanto-and-matthew)

Answer (score 1):

You main_url path incorrect, correct path should be:

```
$this->data['main_url'] = FCPATH . 'assets/themes/' . $name;
```